# Merge Duplicate values in Objects if more than one Objects fields are similar

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am trying to merge duplicate values if more than one same fields are exists in another object.

In below example - I have multiple objects of same **asset_id** and **event_code** which is repeated so I need to keep one and merge their **value**. I tried to do that but not getting the proper solution and output for the same.

```
const transaction = [{
    value: 5,
    asset_id: 'ABC',
    event_code : 1
}, {
    value: 15,
    asset_id: 'HGF',
    event_code : 1
}, {
    value: 15,
    asset_id: 'XYZ',
    event_code : 2
}, {
    value: 20,
    asset_id: 'XYZ',
    event_code : 2
}, {
    value: 25,
    asset_id: 'DEF',
    event_code : 3
}, {
    value: 20,
    asset_id: 'HGF',
    event_code : 3
}, {
    value: 20,
    asset_id: 'HGF',
    event_code : 3
},
{
    value: 10,
    asset_id: 'ABC',
    event_code : 1
}];
 
let newArr = [];
transaction.forEach(function (obj, ind, arr) {
    if (ind === arr.length - 1 || obj.asset_id !== arr[ind + 1].asset_id && obj.event_code!== arr[ind + 1].event_code) {
        newArr.push(obj);
    } else {
        arr[ind + 1].value+= obj.value;
    }
});
 
console.log(newArr)
```

**Expected Output Should be like this :**

```
[{
   value: 15,
   asset_id: 'ABC',
   event_code: 1
}, {
   value: 15,
   asset_id: 'HGF',
   event_code: 1
}, {
   value: 35,
   asset_id: 'XYZ',
   event_code: 2
} {
   value: 25,
   asset_id: 'DEF',
   event_code: 3
}, {
   value: 40,
   asset_id: 'HGF',
   event_code: 3
}]
```

Answer (score -1):

**here is the solution for you**

**updated code**

```js
    const arr = [{
    value: 5,
    asset_id: 'ABC',
    event_code : 1
}, {
    value: 15,
    asset_id: 'HGF',
    event_code : 1
}, {
    value: 15,
    asset_id: 'XYZ',
    event_code : 2
}, {
    value: 20,
    asset_id: 'XYZ',
    event_code : 2
}, {
    value: 25,
    asset_id: 'DEF',
    event_code : 3
}, {
    value: 20,
    asset_id: 'HGF',
    event_code : 3
}, {
    value: 20,
    asset_id: 'HGF',
    event_code : 3
},
{
    value: 10,
    asset_id: 'ABC',
    event_code : 1
}];
    const fun = (ar)=>{
     const output = ar.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      const tmp = prev.find(e => (e.asset_id===curr.asset_id) && (e.event_code===curr.event_code));
        if (tmp) {
          tmp.value = curr.value+tmp.value;
        } else {
          prev.push({
            asset_id: curr.asset_id,
            event_code: curr.event_code,
            value : curr.value
          });
        }
        return prev;
      }, []);
      return output
    }
    console.log(fun(arr))
```

Comment: Not working for me as expected. I am expecting the below output :

[{
   value: 15,
   asset_id: 'ABC',
   event_code: 1
}, {
   value: 15,
   asset_id: 'HGF',
   event_code: 1
}, {
   value: 35,
   asset_id: 'XYZ',
   event_code: 2
} {
   value: 25,
   asset_id: 'DEF',
   event_code: 3
}, {
   value: 40,
   asset_id: 'HGF',
   event_code: 3
}]

Comment: @Krishna thanks for pointout the mistake and sorry for the mistake  I have updated the code can you check that once please. if  its helpfull can you mark my answer as right

Comment: The use of `Array.find` in the `.reduce()` callback makes your solution run in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one approach. We:

- Build a map-of-maps, keyed by `asset_id`

  - Whose values are maps, keyed by `event_code`

    - Whose values are lists of transactions
      sharing a common `asset_id` and `event_code`

  ```
  function buildMapOfMaps( transactionList ) {
    const mapOfMaps = new Map();

    for (const t of transactionList ) {
      let map = mapOfMaps.get( t.asset_id );

      if !map {
        map = new Map();
        mapOfMaps.set(t.asset_id,map);
      }

      let transactions = map.get( t.event_code );
      if (!transactions) {
        transactions = [];
        m.set( t.event_code, transactions );
      }

      transactions.push( t );

    }

    return mapOfMaps;
  }
  ```
- Once we have that, we iterate over the map-of-maps, and roll up those transactions sharing a common `asset_id` and `event_code` into a single transaction

  ```
  function rollUpCommonTransactions( mapOfMaps ) {
    const rollup = [];

    for ( const map of mapOfMaps.values() ) {
      for ( const transactions of map.values() ) {
        const summary = transactions.reduce( (x,y) => {
          x.value += y.value;
          return x;
        });
        rollup.push(summary);
      }
    }

    return rollup;
  }
  ```

Then it's just a matter of putting it all together:

```
function mergeTransactions( transactionList ) {
  const mapOfMaps = buildMapOfMaps(transactionList)
  const rollup = rollUpCommonTransactions(mapOfMaps);

  return rollup;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track but, rather than be concerned about the next element:

- See if you can `Array#`find the current element (same `asset_id` and `event_code`) in `newArr`
- If found, just increment the found element's value by `obj.value`
- And if not found, add the current element to `newArr`

You could as well use `Array#findIndex` - `(index)` in which case `old = newArr[index]`

```js
const transaction = [{ value: 5, asset_id: 'ABC', event_code : 1 }, { value: 15, asset_id: 'HGF', event_code : 1 }, { value: 15, asset_id: 'XYZ', event_code : 2 }, { value: 20, asset_id: 'XYZ', event_code : 2 }, { value: 25, asset_id: 'DEF', event_code : 3 }, { value: 20, asset_id: 'HGF', event_code : 3 }, { value: 20, asset_id: 'HGF', event_code : 3 }, { value: 10, asset_id: 'ABC', event_code : 1 }];
 
let newArr = [];
transaction.forEach(function (obj) {
    const old = newArr.find(
        ({asset_id,event_code}) => 
        asset_id === obj.asset_id && event_code === obj.event_code
    );
    if (old) {
        old.value += obj.value;
    } else {
        newArr.push(obj);
    }
});
 
console.log(newArr)
```